# Безопасность данных массива GET

Tags: php, база-данных, безопасность

Не совсем точное название. В общем ближе к сути.

У меня есть форма на одной странице, в которой я записываю одно слово. Обработка формы проходит в проверочном файле и возвращает массив $_GET примерно такого типа: `idw=3&ida=3`. Дело в том что если эти значения заменить то пользователь сможет спокойно подобрать неправильную комбинацию, на один вопрос сделать другой ответ. Что бы он этого не мог сделать нужно сделать какой-то проверочный код или проще. Если я в массив GET буду передавать сами слова-ответы. Но и так есть вероятность подбора. (выходит так: `idw=Щука&idsa=Я%20многое%20видал`)

Алгоритм работы сайта:

- Пользователь вводит слово в форме и жмет отправить.
- Проверочная страница принимает слово. Проводятся действия над ним. Если слова еще нет в базе то его туда добавляет, после чего во всех случаях выбирается один ответ и отправляется пользователю GET массивом обратно на index.php с формой.
- На этой странице изначально были запросы, кторые брали ID из GET массива и вытаскивали сами слова. Теперь эта страница прямиком получает сами слова и просто выводит их из `$_GET['idw']` и других...
- Никакой регистрации на сайте нет, это по сути обучающийся бот, он пополняет свою базу с помощью пользователей.

Нужно сделать так что бы изменение массива в адресной строке не изменило/запретило отображение неправильной комбинации вопроса-ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например хранить ключ в таблице и искать по нему. Подобрать будет очень сложно. Вот как я это сделал бы:

```
echo md5(uniqid());
```

Выдаст данный код ключ вида: 8203793574c1abf39a78837a19e7d118 
Думаю сама идея ясна. Реализаций и фантазий много. Удачного кодинга...

Comment: Но ключ будет передаваться GET массивом? Пользователь же сможет его взять и отправить с данными. Очевидно я чего-то не понял.

Comment: Можете оставить в качестве параметра только ключ и делать выборку по нему.

Comment: Подождите, можете описать алгоритм действий? Я не совсем понимаю. Ключ хранить в сессии или где? У пользователя ведь не должно быть этого ключа иначе вновь будет уязвимость.

Comment: Вы данные где храните? Если в БД, то создайте поле key. И выборку делайте по key. Если полностью опишите свою задачу, то будет намного проще помочь

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, добавив алгоритм работы сайта.

Comment: Ну так при добавлении вопроса, присвойте ему ключ. И при отображении выводите при помощи ключа, а не ID или названию.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38629/discussion-between-levelleor-and-urmuz-tagizade).